# JavaScript - How to add onclick event dynamically passing in a specific value?

Tags: javascript, events

Could you please have a quick look at the sample code

http://jsfiddle.net/vXvs2/

I don't know if its clear, but what it's supposed to do is show what `i` was when the event was created. Instead what I think it's doing is showing the value of `i` when the event is fired.

How would I solve my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting onclick to use current value of variable in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048561/setting-onclick-to-use-current-value-of-variable-in-loop) and a few million others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the loop's body in a function, to create a closure:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    (function(i){ //i inside this function is a local var; not affected by i++
        arr[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(i);
            return false;
        };
    })(i); //Invoke the function, pass variable i 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXvs2/4/

Comment: :) Perfect, I've been looking for this for ages. +1

Comment: Additionally, you can also pass `arr[i]`, in case the DOM node gets modified. http://jsfiddle.net/vXvs2/5/