# Google Maps API v3 Multiple Info Boxes not opening on click

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

Can somebody please explain why my Google Maps info windows are only opening at the bottom left marker?
See here for the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vj3nw/7/

When I click on *any* of the markers, only the bottom-left one is opened. I would like the marker that is clicked to open.

I believe the problem is due to the loop below, and this question seems to have the same problem [Setting onclick to use current value of variable in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048561/setting-onclick-to-use-current-value-of-variable-in-loop)

"The problem you were hitting is that javascript doesn't use block scope. Instead all variables have a lifetime of their containing function. So there was only ever one a captured in all of the onclick functions and they all see it's final value."

I just can't quite translate that solution to mine.

Many thanks.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: flightPlanCoordinates[i],
        icon: Symbol,
        map: map
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent("hello");

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating your markers and adding the listeners in their own function, called from the loop like the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj3nw/10/) works.

```
function create_marker(i,flightPlanCoordinates,Symbol,map){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: flightPlanCoordinates[i],
            icon: Symbol,
            map: map
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent("hello" + i);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great. Is this an example of a closure?